# Comparar respuesta de API con datos de la bd - Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

Estoy consumiendo un api y la respuesta que obtengo la transformo a un array, hago un foreach para recorrer esos resultados y resgitro los datos en dos tablas diferentes por ORM, si vuelvo a realizar nuevamente la peticion a la api, este me trae los mismos resultados y los inserta nuevamente en las tablas, como puedo validar que la respuesta que obtengo se encuentra ya en esas dos tablas para que los datos no se repitan?

->Estoy utilizando una version de symfony antigua

->Las dos tablas tienen la misma estructura del API, excepto por el campo "id" => llega vacio

Este es mi codigo:

```html
<?php 

$response = json_decode($response);

//Respuesta API
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'id' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'codigo' => string '01' (length=2)
      public 'producto' => string 'Producto#1' (length=9)     
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'id' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'codigo' => string '02' (length=2)
      public 'producto' => string 'Producto#2' (length=9)     
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'id' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'codigo' => string '03' (length=2)
      public 'producto' => string 'Producto#3' (length=9)    
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'id' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'codigo' => string '04' (length=2)
      public 'producto' => string 'Producto#4' (length=9)    
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'id' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'codigo' => string '05' (length=2)
      public 'producto' => string 'Producto#5' (length=9)     
  5 => 
    object(stdClass)[6]
      public 'id' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'codigo' => string '06' (length=2)
      public 'producto' => string 'Producto#6' (length=9)

  //Recorrer los datos
  foreach ($response as $key => $row){    
 //Guarda datos de la respuesta en variables
 $codigo = $row->codigo;
 $producto = $row->producto;
 
 /* Validar que los resultados obtenidos 
 * no se encuentren en la tablas
 * TablaProducto#1 y
 * TablaProducto#2
 * si no hay datos, insertarlos por ORM a la BD 
 */

 //Insertar datos en TablaProducto#1
 $producto1 = new Productos1();
 $producto1->setCodigo($codigo);
 $producto1->setProducto($producto);
 $producto1->save();

 //Insertar datos en TablaProducto#2
 $producto2 = new Productos2();
 $producto2->setCodigo($codigo);
 $producto2->setProducto($producto);
 $producto2->save();
       
  }//End foreach
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comprueba en base de datos si el código de producto, que se supone que también será un valor único, no existe.

Si no existe ejecutas el insert, si ya existe no haces nada.

```
$product1Repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Productos1::class);

$product = $product1Repository->findOneByCodigo($codigo);

if (!$product)
{
    ...
    producto1->save();

}
```

Luego esto habría que optimizarlo para no hacer tantas consultas a base de datos si las tablas.